# How get latitude and longitude of laptop (wifi) in Google Maps Geolocation API?

Tags: javascript, c++

To get latitude and longitude of a mobile phone we can use Google Maps Geolocation API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro?hl=en) by sending a package with the following format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDfWo.jpg)

The Google Maps Geolocation API returns a location and accuracy radius based on information about cell towers and WiFi nodes that the mobile client can detect. However, I wonder that for a laptop, how the format of a sent package will be. Is there anyone willing to send me a sample format used to get the location of a laptop? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
}
```

and browser colls your callback function with one argument like this:

```
   function setLocation(position) {
        userPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
   };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to use Google Maps Geolocation API or application (C++).

Comment: I think format have to be  the same, so You need to get info about wifi on laptop. But actually I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late to answer, but someone might find this useful.

So, you'll need to Post a request to https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_KEY

The response will be something like this:

```
{
  "location": {
    "lat": 51.0,
    "lng": -0.1
  },
  "accuracy": 1200.4
}
```

You can get a key from [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/)

All the details of the API are here [Geolocation API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro)